# Automating Application Actions

Tags: android, testing, automated-tests

I haven't been able to find something sufficient through normal searches on Google etc except for maybe http://appium.io. I'm interested in finding a tool / library I can use to automate android application actions for testing. I do not have the original source of the apk, but I'd like to program actions and run them through an emulator to act against the android program. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you could use the [UI Automator](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-automator) for automating just anything through `adb`.

while if you don't have the project's source code, there won't be test & coverage results.

nevertheless, the automation code would have to be executed with the [JUnit4 runner](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/runners/JUnit4.html).